# Why is とき used with instantaneous verb 気づく?

Tags: grammar, verbs

> 気づいたときには たまっているもの
> You'll save [enough money] before you know it.

At least based on the dictionary definition and examples, 気づくseems to be an instantaneous verb, "realize". How then does とき fit in this sentence? I thought とき means while doing something.

Comment: Do these help? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30926  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11699  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11975  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19332

Comment: とき means not only *while* but also *when*.

Comment: Maybe you have mixed とき and あいだ? とき is typically "when" and あいだ is typically "while".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The questions linked in the comment by @[Eddie Kal](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/30454/), taken together, should answer your question in depth.

In brief, とき literally means "time", and can be used to mean "time *while* doing something", or "time *when* something happens / happened / will happen".

In your sample sentence, we can break things down as follows:

- 気【き】づいたときにはたまっているもの
  [気づいた]{noticed}[とき]{time when  }[に]{at}[は]{  CONTRASTIVE  }[たまっている]{  it is accumulating / accumulated  }[もの]{  REASON}
  *(literal)* At the time you've noticed it, it will have been accumulated, is the reason
  *(idiomatic)* Because before you know it, it'll be saved up